# AWS IoT Subdomain Too Long for AWS IoT Button (Gen 1)

Tags: aws-iot

I'm trying to connect a generation 1 AWS IoT Button (the blue kind) to my AWS IoT core instance.

In the configuration, it says to input a **subdomain** that is 14 characters long so that it can create the endpoint for the button. However, my IoT endpoint is **18** characters long - it has an additional `-ats` at the end of it.

So, while my endpoint is *actually* 
`XXXXXXXXXXXXXX-ats.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com`

It won't let me add the `-ats` at the end of it. So I'm stuck with
`XXXXXXXXXXXXXX.iot.us-west-2.amazonaws.com`.

Is there a way to input the full AWS IoT endpoint? Or is the `-ats` ending not needed and it's another issue with connecting the button to a network?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem trying to manually setup the AWS button.

As an alternative to using the tutorial to configure the button manually, I used the AWS IoT Button Dev application on an iphone.  Using the iPhone app worked.

[Apple App Store](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/aws-iot-button-dev/id1178216626?mt=8)

[Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amazonaws.iotbutton&hl=en_US)

The resulting url in the console still contained the -ats suffix in the endpoint.  I do not know if the app is bypassing the 14 character limitation, or if it is not needed, but this at least got me up and running with the button.  If that is your goal, this should get you going.

Comment: Gonna mark this as the correct answer since the iOS App does in fact work. It would be optimal still to manually set up the AWS IoT Button, but this gets it up and running to AWS IoT Core.

Comment: This is no longer an option because the app seems to reject 1st generation devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can also edit the html on the form in the developer console. The maxlength on the input element named "subdomain" is set to 14. Change that to >=18 and you should be able to submit the form.

Comment: This is not working - server validation fails are returns a 500 error.